# Finding adjacent column values from the last non-null value of a certain column in Snowflake (SQL) using partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partition-by

Say I have the following table:

| ID | T | R |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 3 | Y |
| 1 | 4 |  |
| 1 | 5 |  |
| 1 | 6 | Y |
| 1 | 7 |  |

I would like to add a column which equals the value from column T based on the last non-null value from column R. This means the following:

| ID | T | R | GOAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 1 | 3 | Y |  |
| 1 | 4 | Y | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |  | 4 |
| 1 | 6 | Y | 4 |
| 1 | 7 |  | 6 |

I do have many ID's so I need to make use of the `OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` clause. Also, if possible, I would like to use a single statement, like

```
SELECT *
,      GOAL
FROM TABLE
```

So without any extra select statement.

Comment: Please make sure to tag correctly.  (MS) SQL Server <> Snowflake.  I removed the SQL Server tag for you.

Comment: Shouldn't the 4's in your output be 3 instead? Or at least the `R` value needs to be corrected for 4 in the input table?

Comment: No the output is correct, I want the value of T corresponding to last non-null value from column R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` is in ascending order so just null it out according to `R` and take the maximum looking backward.

```
select *,
    max(case when R is not null then T end)
      over (
        partition by id
        order by T
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) as GOAL
from TBL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c927a5/5